# Error handling without pattern matching in Haskell

Tags: python, haskell, coding-style, pattern-matching, control-structure

I'm trying to write a program that takes two integers on the command line and does something interesting with them.  I would like write the reading/parsing of the integers as easily and imperatively as possible since it should be relatively simple code.

The problem that I'm facing is that in Haskell handling errors is not so simple.  It seems that in Haskell pattern matching is often used.  This seems to make the code slightly harder to follow than the imperative version.

The program would be run like this (in this example it just adds together the two numbers):

```
$ ./my_prog
ERROR: Must run like `./my_prog NUM_A NUM_B`.
$ ./my_prog cat 1
ERROR: Could not parse NUM_A "cat" as integer
$ ./my_prog 10 dog
ERROR: Could not parse NUM_B "dog" as integer
$ ./my_prog 10 1
11
```

Here's is what I would like to do in imperative pseudo-Python:

```
function die (errorMessage):
    print("ERROR: %s" % errorMessage)
    sys.exit(1)

function main ():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        die("Must run program like `%s NUM_A NUM_B`" % sys.progname)

    num_a = 0
    num_b = 0

    try:
        num_a = int(sys.argv[0])
    except:
        die("Could not parse NUM_A \"%s\" as integer" % sys.argv[0])

    try:
        num_b = int(sys.argv[1])
    except:
        die("Could not parse NUM_B \"%s\" as integer" % sys.argv[1])

     doSomethingInteresting(num_a, num_b)

function doSomethingInteresting (num_a, num_b):
    print(num_a + num_b)
```

In python you can basically read the main function from top to bottom and all the error handling is straightforward.  **Is there a way to implement this simple, straightforward error handling in Haskell without doing multiple pattern matchings?**

Here is the Haskell code I came up with that does this same task, but it seems much more complicated than the Python code because of the multiple pattern matching sections.

```
module Main ( main
            )
            where

import System.Environment (getArgs, getProgName)
import System.Exit (ExitCode(..), exitWith)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

die :: String -> IO a
die err = do putStrLn $ "ERROR: " ++ err
             exitWith (ExitFailure 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
        args <- getArgs
        progName <- getProgName
        case args of
            [strNumA, strNumB] -> do
                let maybeNumA = readMaybe strNumA :: Maybe Int
                    maybeNumB = readMaybe strNumB :: Maybe Int
                checkMaybeArgs strNumA maybeNumA strNumB maybeNumB
            _ -> die ("Must run like `" ++ progName ++ " NUM_A NUM_B`.")
    where
        checkMaybeArgs :: String -> Maybe Int -> String -> Maybe Int -> IO ()
        checkMaybeArgs badStrNumA Nothing _ _ =
            die ("Could not parse NUM_A \"" ++ badStrNumA ++ "\" as integer")
        checkMaybeArgs _ _ badStrNumB Nothing =
            die ("Could not parse NUM_B \"" ++ badStrNumB ++ "\" as integer")
        checkMaybeArgs _ (Just numA) _ (Just numB) = doSomethingInteresting numA numB

        doSomethingInteresting :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
        doSomethingInteresting numA numB = print $ numA + numB
```

(Also if there is anything else wrong with my Haskell style I would be very grateful for any corrections.)

edit: I recently found a blog post talking about the many different ways to handle exceptions in Haskell.  It is somewhat related:

http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I'd write this (without using any external libraries)

```
import Text.Read
import Text.Printf
import System.Environment
import Control.Monad
import System.Exit


parsingFailure :: String -> String -> IO a
parsingFailure name val = printf "ERROR: Couldn't parse %s : %s as an integer\n" 
                                  name val >> exitWith (ExitFailure 1)

validateArgs :: [String] -> IO (Integer, Integer)
validateArgs [a, b] = liftM2 (,) (parse "VAL A" a) (parse "VAL B" b)
  where parse name s = maybe (parsingFailure name s) return $ readMaybe s
validateArgs _      = putStrLn "Wrong number of args" >> exitWith (ExitFailure 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (a, b) <- getArgs >>= validateArgs
  print $ a + b
```

The interesting bit of course being `validateArgs`. First we do a single pattern match, but from then on we just use the `maybe` combinator to nicely abstract away our pattern matching. This results in far cleaner code IMO. The `maybe` combinator takes a default value  `b` and a continuation `a -> b` and unwraps `Maybe a` to `b`. In this case, our default value is a parsing failure, and our continuation injects `a` into the `IO` monad.

Comment: How would this change if you did use external libraries?

Comment: @illabout I'd probably use a proper command-line argument parsing library. I'm lazy and this is work that others have already done. For something this small it's probably not worth it, but still

Comment: I thought about using something like optparse-applicative, but I felt like it would be overkill for this small example.

Comment: @illabout Fair enough. If I've answered your question btw, you can check the check mark by my answer to mark this thread as "solved"

Comment: Thanks.  I will wait a little more for any different answers, but I really like your answer.  Assuming I don't get any better answers, I will pick yours.

Answer (score 4):

Although I like @jozefgs solution for its brevity, I dislike that it uses `exitWith`. Sure, it works fine for such a small example as this, but in general I think it's a bad idea to terminate the program "prematurely" like that. It's indeed a property I dislike of the Python version as well. In any case, my solution follows, and I'll explain a few parts of it below.

```
import System.Environment (getProgName, getArgs)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

doSomethingInteresting :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
doSomethingInteresting a b = print (a + b)

readWith :: Read a => (String -> e) -> String -> Either e a
readWith err str = maybe (Left $ err str) return $ readMaybe str


main = do
  progName <- getProgName
  args     <- getArgs

  either putStrLn id $ do
    (a,b) <- case args of
               [a,b] -> return (a,b)
               _     -> Left ("Must run program like `" ++ progName ++ " NUM_A NUM_B`")

    num_a <- readWith (\s -> "Could not parse NUM_A \"" ++ s ++ "\" as integer") a
    num_b <- readWith (\s -> "Could not parse NUM_B \"" ++ s ++ "\" as integer") b

    return $ doSomethingInteresting num_a num_b
```

I know there's a pattern matching in this, but that is really the cleanest way to express what I want. If the list has two elements, I want them out of it. If it doesn't, I want an error message. There is no neater way of expressing that.

But there are a few other things going on here that I want to highlight.

#### Single exit point

First, which I've already mentioned, the program does not have several "exit points", i.e. it doesn't terminate the program in the middle of something. Imagine if the `main` function was not the main function but somewhere deeper down, and you had some files open or whatnot in a function above. You would want to go out the proper way to close the files and so on. That's why I choose to not terminate the program, but rather let it run its course and just don't do the calculations if it doesn't have the number.

Just terminating the program is rarely a good idea. Often, you have things you want to save, files you want to close, state you want to restore and so on.

#### `Either` annotates errors

It might not be very evident for a beginner, but what `readWith` basically does is try to `read` something, and if it succeeds, it returns `Right <read value>`. If it fails, it will return `Left <error message>`, where the error message can depend on what string it tried to read.

So, in this program,

```
λ> readWith errorMessage "15"
Right 15
```

while

```
λ> readWith errorMessage "crocodile"
Left "Cannot read \"crocodile\" as an integer, dummy!"
```

The `Either` type is great when you want to transport a value but there might occur an error along the way, and you want to keep the error message around until you know what to do about the error. The community consensus is that `Right` should indicate the "correct" value and `Left` should indicate that some error occurred.

`Either` values are a sort of more controlled (read: better) exception system.

#### `do` syntax is your friend

The `do` syntax is very handy for handling errors. As soon as any computation results in a `Left` value, Haskell will break out of the `do` block with the error message carried by the `Left`. This means that the entire inner `do` block will in this case either result in something similar to

```
Right (print 41)
```

or something like

```
Left "Could not parse NUM_A \"crocodile\" as integer"
```

The `either` function then makes sure to either print the error message or just return the `IO` action that is the `Right` value. It might be weird coming from Python that you can store a `print` action as a value, but that's normal in Haskell. We say that I/O actions are *first class citizens* in Haskell. In other words, we can pass them around and store them in data structures, and then we decide ourselves when we want them executed.

Comment: This is a really good answer.  If I could accept two answers I would.  I agree about not exiting early from a program, but in my specific case (and in @jozefg's answer), I think it is acceptable because there is nothing to clean up.  But in almost every other case, your answer would be the better answer.  Thank you for taking the time to write the nice explanation.  It helped me with understanding the "Nothing"s and "Left"s are treated when inside the Maybe and Either monads.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my go at it:

```
module Main where

import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import System.Environment (getProgName, getArgs)

main = getArgs >>= \argv -> case argv of
  [x, y] -> case (readMaybe x, readMaybe y) of
    (Nothing, _      ) -> error $
      "ERROR: Could not parse NUM_A " ++ show x ++ " as integer"
    (_      , Nothing) -> error $
      "ERROR: Could not parse NUM_B " ++ show y ++ " as integer"
    (Just a , Just b ) -> print $ a + b
  _ -> do
    pname <- getProgName
    error $ "ERROR: Must run like `" ++ pname ++ " NUM_A NUM_B`."
```

Notice how you can pattern match on a tuple to match on multiple expressions at once, saving you from needing multiple embedded case expressions.

Comment: This is still using two pattern matches (the two case statements), which I wanted to avoid, but it is still nicer than the code I wrote.  IMHO, This code (and my code) doesn't read top-to-bottom quite like the python code.

Comment: That's true. Generally in Haskell we favor this kind of "nested" decision making, with a tree of pattern matching, over the more imperative style in your Python code. That's probably since it's easier to statically check; when you match `[x, y]` instead of checking for `length == 2`, the compiler guarantees you can't accidentally index an element that isn't in the list.

Comment: @Onyxite I disagree, most code I read doesn't nest case expressions because it's harder to read. And it's completely orthogonal to typechecking. Most code breaks things into small (<5 line) functions.

Comment: I agree with @jozefg, nested cases are hard to read and I tend to stay away from them. Although this solution is concise, it does little to improve on the pattern matching mess which was the OP's main concern.

Comment: @jozefg, it's not just typechecking, it's also the scope in which values are bound. The Python code, which checks `if len(sys.argv) != 2:` and then later refers to `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`, requires the programmer to verify the check happens before indexing the array. Haskell's `case` ensures you can't accidentally refer to the first element if it isn't there, because the nesting creates the scope of the variables.

Comment: And I absolutely agree, once the logic gets more complex, the higher-order functions you used like `liftM2` and `maybe` are the way to go. But that's not a completely different thing from my code -- it just hides the nesting, but it's still there under the hood. The control flow is still not "top to bottom" like the Python code is, which is what @illabout was asking about.

Comment: One thing I liked about this example is using `error` to handle the error cases instead of just immediately exiting the program.  This would allow some sort of error handling if this function were being called from some other function (for example, if this function wasn't the main function but some other function deeper in your program).  Of course, if that was the case, it might be better to handle errors with the Maybe or Either monad instead.

Comment: Yes, `Maybe` and `Either` are far better for general error handling. I used `error` because it happened to do exactly what you'd want here: print a string to stderr and then quit with non-zero status.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take at it:

```
import System.Environment
import Text.Printf
import Text.Read


main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  either putStrLn (uncurry doSomethingInteresting) $ parseArgs args


doSomethingInteresting :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
doSomethingInteresting a b = print $ a + b


parseArgs :: [String] -> Either String (Int, Int)
parseArgs [a, b] = do
  a' <- parseArg "A" a
  b' <- parseArg "B" b
  return (a', b')
parseArgs _ = fail "Wrong number of args"


parseArg :: String -> String -> Either String Int
parseArg name arg
  | Just x <- readMaybe arg = return x
  | otherwise = fail $ printf "Could not parse NUM_%s \"%s\" as integer" name arg
```

Or for Applicative fans, another way of writing `parseArgs`:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> Either String (Int, Int)
parseArgs [a, b] = (,) <$> parseArg "A" a <*> parseArg "B" b
parseArgs _ = fail "Wrong number of args"
```